# C language & | ~ << >>

Tags: c

I just learning C. Could someone explain that what are they using for ? these operators. in a real industrial case..thanks.

like:

when I need these? :

```
~X 
n = n & 0177
x = x | 1211
```

Please tell me.

Comment: Used for bitmasks and flags. Suggest you keep reading, then ask us.

Comment: Is anything stopping you from opening a book? If so, then that should be a far greater worry for you than the meaning of those operators.

Comment: read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Comment: Hardware address filter, masking, encoding and decoding, etc.

Comment: In fairness, it's hard to read/search for something when you don't know what it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fundamental and so there are many potential applications, but here's a specific industrial example:

Suppose you're sending a bunch of command and/or status info between devices.  To avoid wasting bandwidth (particularly if you're using a slower type of connection such an old 9-pin serial connection, which are still used on industrial devices), you very well may "pack" and "unpack" the data.  In the case of two-state signals, this means that each byte can hold up to eight independent statuses.  To get the status of bit 6, you could do something like this:

```
status = (dataByte & 0x40) >> 6;
```

In the above line, 0x40 is a bitmask that results in all bits being zero except for bit 6.  The shift right by 6 converts the resulting value--0x40 or 0x00--to 1 or 0.

Take a look at this brief section for standard, related examples:  [Bit Manipulation in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation#Bit_manipulation_in_the_C_programming_language)